# HTML+CSS div container

Tags: html, css

Why isn't the red box contained inside of the pageTopWrap div? Everything appears to be correct but its not working

```css
body { margin: 0; }  
#pageTop {
    background: url(style/headersliver.png) repeat-x;
    height: 71px;
}
#pageTop > #pageTopWrap {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 71px;
}
#pageTop > #pageTopWrap > #pageTopLogo {
    float: left:
    height: 71px;
    width: 100px;
}
#pageTop > #pageTopWrap > #pageTopRest {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    height: 71px;
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div id="pageTop">
    <div id="pageTopWrap">
        <div id="pageTopLogo">
            <a href="http://www.link"><img src="style/apng.png" alt="logo" title="Logo Title"></img></a>
        </div>
        <div id="pageTopRest"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="pageMiddle"></div>
<div id="pageBottom"></div>
```

Basically it should have the bar at top. with the logo, that all works fine, but when try and add the container field for stuff inside the pageTopWrap it doesn't get contained inside the pageTopWrap.

[image: This is what my current code outputs]

The red box should be on top of the gray bars.

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhbMN.png)

Comment: can you explain the question

Comment: Well basically, Im not sure why my pageTopRest div isnt being contained inside of the pageTopWrap div, the pageTopLogo worked perfectly, but pageTopRest div seems to not be inheriting the parent properties

Comment: you have an error in your css `float: left:` should be `float: left;` this is preventing correct floating, and invalidating the next css rule (`height:71px`) and is pushing the `float:right` element from having "space" to sit higher

Comment: omfg are you serious, im an idiot, sorry for wasting your guys time, thanks though cant beleive i missed that, looked it over like 10 times

Comment: This is why there is a CSS (and HTML) validator for your use.

Comment: Based on the comments I assume your problem has been solved, but I would like to point out that your selectors are overly specific and some parts of it seem redundant. A document can only have one object with a specific ID; unless you define different styles based on the relative layout between pages, you can remove everything in front of the id selector.

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo `float: left:` under `#pageTop > #pageTopWrap > #pageTopLogo`

It should be `float: left;` Notice the semi-colon. Corrected code follows:

```
#pageTop > #pageTopWrap > #pageTopLogo {
  float: left;
  height: 71px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have misplaced the ending character. It should be `;` not `:`.

Replace `float: left:` with `float: left;`.